# Connection Dropped when sending large response from vb.net web service

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, connection-close

I have a VB.net web service that returns JSON that works fine.  Once the response gets to a certain size though, the client browser says that the server has closed the connection and sent no data.  This is true using IE, Chrome, or Firefox.  The magic size seems to be about 16383 records, or about 1.13MB of data.  I know this is slightly large for a web service, but please go with this for now.

The connection is just closed, ie not a 500 or other error from the server.  I also see the same behavior on IIS 7.5 and on ASP.net Development server from the IDE.

Using firebug, fiddler, and wireshark all seem to show that the server is closing the connection.

Since I can have this happen in the IDE using debug mode, I can step through the service and see that the service is invoked, calls out to the db, gets all the records properly, and then exits the sub normally.  I also verified that this is not a data issue.

To attempt to trace, I added this param to my system.web

When running the web service, the Trace.axd shows the result as 200, so it would seem that the web server is happy, but the connection is still getting closed. This trace does not show much detail though.

Is there any know reason why the server or client would close the connection like this?  Is there any known response size limits using IIS in this way?  Is there any way to trace this down better?

Thanks much.

Comment: Are you sure its size and not timeout causing it to close?

Comment: Hi, definitely not timeout.  16382 records work, >= 16383 don't.  And the DB query runs quick, no more than a second or two.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have this figured out. The way I found the problem is via WCF tracing: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx. It was giving me this error: Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'. Change the object graph or increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota. So I did just what it said and upped MaxItemsInObjectGraph and problem solved. I'm not sure how the math works though as 16383 items all have 3 fields, so that should have been 49149 objects, but whatever. Upping this solved this issue.